# What does it mean, "Put a little bark on that and I'll bite"?

Tags: dialogue, super-troopers-2

In [*Super Troopers 2* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0859635/), Farva meets Gwenevieve at a shopping mall:

Farva: Hey, Gwenevieve how about the two of us go over to
the Saskatchuan Palace and get a wang dang doodle?

Genevieve Aubois: Uh, non.

Farva: Ooh, woof woof. Put a little bark on that and I'll bite.

Comment: barking up the wrong tree: to be wrong about the reason for something or the way to achieve something

Answer (score 2):

What she's essentially saying is, "I'm not convinced that you really don't want to go."  If she came off more convincing (adding a little "bark" to her response), then she'd believe the response (i.e., she'd "bite" that the response was legit).

This is why you'll note that Genevieve scoffs at Farva and then leaves.

Comment: Maybe a slightly better translation would be "Reject the offer more strongly (= add some figurative barking like a dog) and I'll believe you"